# Redirect after Login

Tags: javascript, php, html, authentication

How can i auto login and load another page. I am able to auto login but i want auto redirect to http://website.com/xxx.php

i used the following code, auto login working fine but redirect the page

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="login_page_url">
    <select name="uni_url" id="logServer" class="validate[required]">
        <option class="" value="customer" fbUrl="" cookieName="">

        </option>
    </select>
    <input id="edit-submitted-username" name="username" type="text" maxlength="128" value="username" class="" />
    <input id="edit-submitted-password" class="form-text required" name="password" type="password" value="password" class="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="loginKid" name="kid" value="" />
</form>
<script>
    document.loginForm.submit();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can process the login using PHP. Javascript is executed in the client side, and PHP in the server. For a login, an execution in the server side makes sense. 
In order to do that, you declare your form like this:

```
<form action="./processLogin.php" method="post" name="loginForm">
```

Then create the file `processLogin.php` in the same folder you're at (because we declared so in the code above), which shall contain the following code:

```
<?php
session_start(); // if necessary

// retrieve username:
$user= $_REQUEST["username"]; // The REQUEST parameter is the value of the attribute 'name' of the 'input's of your form. 
//In your declaration: '<input ... name="username" ...'

// retrieve the password as well:
$pass = $_REQUEST["password"]; //same as above

//check stuff (user exists, password is correct...)

//and at some point, if everything is OK :
header('Location: http://website.com/xxx.php');
exit;
//remember, these 2 lines come together

?>
```

Comment: Always use `exit;` after a redirect with `header()`, if the user is accessing via something else than a browser the remaining code is executed and you may be exposing sensitive information.

Comment: Yup, just realized, and edited, thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Xdsasdf but no luck i put next to `<script>    document.loginForm.submit();</script>`

Comment: Hi, @Aaron, I assume you're not including php code within the `script` tags, you can't do that. Nevertheless I edited my answer to show a valid method to process the login.

Answer (score 0):

You could try javascript

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

But google already knew that. :-(